# I'm looking for a word that decribes the different types of dashes in the image

Tags: single-word-requests

In the image below, the green dashes represent having a percentage of something while the gray dashes represent not having that percentage. I might say, there are three active segments and three inactive segments. This is for technical documentation so conciseness is desired. There was a related question I saw about a word that describes the intervening spaces, and interstice was suggested, so hoping there is a word for this.

[image: On and Off Dashes]

> The credits progress bar should be divided into ______ for which some are green and some gray indicating amounts earned or not earned respectively.

Of course the word *segment* springs to mind, but thought there might be something else.

Comment: Can you give us an example of you you plan on using it? Like a sentence or two?

Comment: [_**Progress bar**_](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Progress_bar), it's called. Unclear, your question.

Comment: @Hank, The credits progress bar should be divided into ______ for which some are green and some gray indicating amounts earned or not earned respectively. Of course the word segment springs to mind, but thought there might be something else.

Comment: Better to ask on [graphicdesign.se] or [ux.se]. :)

Comment: I think if this is better to ask on Graphic Design or User Experience then there are too many StackExchanges! lol

Comment: Never a true statement

Comment: Lines are made up of segments. But this is a line made up of the geometrical figure called a rectangle, aka a rectangular box.

Comment: Stick with segment, I think it is the best fit here.

Comment: @Hank ha  ha, fair enough. We can always use more Stacks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Of course the word **segment** springs to mind

I think you should go with it. It's very clear and is already used to describe graphics like yours.

For example, [this scholarly paper](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity12/sec12-final209.pdf) uses the term "segmented bars" to describe meters similar to yours, like this one from PayPal:

[image]

I'm also reminded of [segmented bar graphs](http://www.rossmanchance.com/iscam/examplesch6.html).

Comment: yea, I lost my magnifying glass for my Oxford dictionary, so this will do, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Call them ***steps***, or ***blocks***, used for 'discrete progress bars'. For example, see this question posted in User Experience SE: [Showing progress for a long many-step process with a discrete progress bar?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/35519/78588)

Answer (score 0):

I personally like the concept of [***sections***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/section).

> Any of the more or less distinct parts into which something is or may be divided or from which it is made up:
>   *‘I unscrewed every section of copper pipe, from the roof tank to the hot-water cylinder’*

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/section